# How do I force a gem file to be installed when the the dependency doesn't match?

Tags: jekyll, bundle, jekyll-extensions

I'm building a Jekyll site and I need to be able to convert pages to PDF. I want to use [`jekyll-pdf`](https://github.com/abemedia/jekyll-pdf) but when I include it, bundle tells me it's incompatible:

```
Because every version of jekyll-pdf depends on jekyll >= 3.1, < 4.A
  and Gemfile depends on jekyll ~> 4.3.3,
  jekyll-pdf cannot be used.
```

Looking at the `jekyll-pdf` repo it seems like it's no longer maintained so I don't expect this to change. Is there a way to force bundle to install that gem even though the dependency isn't valid?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to install existing `jekyll-pdf` gem if your `jekyll` version is `4.x`. But you can fork `jekyll-pdf` repo and upgrade the jekyll dependency in `.gemspec` file, like:

```rb
  spec.add_runtime_dependency "jekyll", ">= 2.0", "~> 4.0"
```

Then use your updated version in Gemfile, like:

```rb
gem 'jekyll-pdf', git: 'https://github.com/your-github/forked-repo'
```

Be aware that `jekyll-pdf` gem might work only for older versions of `jekyll`, using newer might result in unexpected behaviours or bugs.